# python return not & and meaning?

Tags: python

I was reading the following article:

http://stefaanlippens.net/python-asynchronous-subprocess-pipe-reading

I was not sure what the following function was returning:

```
def eof(self):
    '''Check whether there is no more content to expect.'''
    return not self.is_alive() and self._queue.empty()
```

Looked at question below:

[python and / or operators return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477850/python-and-or-operators-return-value)

```
x and y, if x is false, then x, else y
```

What is x in this case? Is it 
      self.is_alive() 
or 
      not self.is_alive()

Comment: `return (not (self.is_alive()))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For expressions without parentheses, Python uses a concept called [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) to determine what to evaluate first.

The `not` operator has a higher precedence than the `and` operator, so your expression is parsed as:

```
    (not self.is_alive())
and 
    self._queue.empty()
```

and `self.is_alive()` is called first. If that returns `True`, the `not` expression produces `False`, and the `self._queue.empty()` expression is *not even run*. The `False` result from `not self.is_alive()` is returned. After all, there is no way the `and` expression can become true with the left-hand-side of the expression already determined to be false.

If `self.is_alive()` returns `False` on the other hand, `not False` becomes `True`, and the result of `self._queue.empty()` is returned from the whole expression.

So, provided `self._queue.empty()` your function returns a boolean, the `eof()` method will return `False` if the object is still alive *or* the queue is not empty. It'll return True only if the object is no longer alive *and* the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
 return not self.is_alive() and self._queue.empty()
```

I think `return not` is not the phrase, rather `not self.is_alive()` is the phrase which will give you `True` when `self.is_alive()` is `False` and vice verca

Consider this:

```
return not self.is_alive() and self._queue.empty()
```

If you know about `short-circuiting` of conditional statement, you will know that,

if  `self.is_alive()` is `true`, `false` is evaluated for this portion and it won't go to `self._queue.empty()`. It will return immediately.

But if `self.is_alive()` is `false`, `true` is evaluated from first portion, then it will check the second portion.

Answer (score 1):

it is `not self.isalive()`

the other alternative would be `not(self.isalive() and self.queue.empty())`

since `not` is higher precedence than `and` it is  before the and

Comment: `not` has higher precedence than `and`.