# Usage of the and operator in this return statement

Tags: python, recursion

I am using the simple recursive function below to add together all the digits in a number.  My question is why is the initial 'return n' needed (it does not work without it) rather than just going to the n%10?

```
def sumDigits(n):
    return n and n%10 + sumDigits(n//10)  
sumDigits(123)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise what are the recursive calls doing if the function never returns anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every recursive function *must* have a base case, otherwise recursion continues until you hit the limits of your stack. In this case, the base case, or the stopping point of your function, is determining that all digits have already been added (i.e., `n == 0`).

So,

```
def sumDigits(n):
    return n and n % 10 + sumDigits(n // 10)
```

Can (and should) be re-written as:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if n == 0: 
        return n 
    return n % 10 + sumDigits(n // 10)
```

In this case, the base case has been explicitly spelled out using an `if` condition.

In the first case, however, the developer has taken advantage of the "truthiness" of ints and the behaviour of the `and` logical operator.  For more information, see [Strange use of "and" / "or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-pythons-and-operator/47007761#47007761). The working of `and` in the first scenario is described as:

> Return the first falsy value if there are any, else return the last
>   value in the expression.

"Falsy" values include 0 and 0.0 (relevant to your problem) among other things. When `n == 0`, the expression short circuits and 0 is returned. Otherwise, the second expression to the right of the `and` is evaluated and returned.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is extremely helpful

Comment: I am new to this.  I think its good to go now - let me know if not.