# Logical operator explanation in Python

Tags: python, variables

Output of this code is 2. Can anyone explain how ?

```
   > a = True
   > b = 0
   > c = 2
   > print((a OR b ) AND c)
```

Comment: did you read the documentation ? What was unclear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange use of python's and / or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-pythons-and-or-operator)

Answer (score 1):

**Logical AND (and):**

Return the first Falsey value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.

**Logical OR (or):**

Return the first Truthy value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.