# Error in using operators in function arguments (isinstance) in Python

Tags: python, arguments, isinstance

I can't seem to wrap my head around the output of this function:

```
def is_integer(num1, num2):
        if isinstance(num1 and num2, int):
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'

print(is_integer(1.4, 2))
```

This will output 'Yes', but it shouldn't as 1.4 and 2 are not both integers.
Any help?

Comment: `num1 and num2` means `num1` if it's falsey (`False`, `None`, zero, or empty), otherwise `num2`. That probably isn't what you wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the [`and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) operator works in Python is:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

In Python, `None`, `False`, numeric zeros, and empty collections are false; almost everything else is true.<sup>1</sup>

So, `1.4 and 2` means `2`, because `1.4` is not zero.

So, `isinstance(1.4 and 2, int)` means `isinstance(2, int)`.

And `2` is an `int`.

---

What you probably wanted here is:

```
if isinstance(num1, int) and isinstance(num2, int):
```

… or:

```
if all(isinstance(num, int) for num in (num1, num2)):
```

---

<sub>1. To avoid confusion between the specific `True` and `False` values and the more abstract idea of true and false values, most Python developers refer to `None`/`False`/zero/empty as "falsey" rather than "false", and everything else as "truthy" rather than "true". But the documentation avoids this cutesiness, and I'm quoting from the docs here.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(num1 and num2, int)
```

Is the same as

```
t1 = num1 and num2
if isinstance(t1, int)
```

The result of an and between two numbers returns the first Falsy value if there are any, else returns the last value in the expression.

Some examples:

```
In [24]: 1.4 and 2
Out[24]: 2

In [25]: 1.4 and 2 and 3
Out[25]: 3

In [26]: 1.4 and 0 and 2
Out[26]: 0
```

For more information, see [Strange use of "and" / "or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-pythons-and-or-operator/47007761#47007761).

---

If you want to test both, you have to do them separately:

```
def is_integer(num1, num2):
    if isinstance(num1, int) and isinstance(num2, int):
        return 'Yes'        
    return 'No'
```

Which is a more wieldy way of writing

```
def is_integer(num1, num2):
    if all(isinstance(n, int) for n in (num1, num2)):
        return 'Yes'        
    return 'No'
```

...with the `all` function which generalises to more than 2 arguments.

Better still, have your function accept a variable number of arguments:

```
def is_integer(*args):
    if all(isinstance(n, int) for n in args):
        return 'Yes'
    return 'No'
```

Better still, return a boolean result:

```
def is_integer(*args):
    return all(isinstance(n, int) for n in args)
```

Comment: "As long as both numbers != 0, t1 == True" - no, `and` in Python returns one of its arguments. If neither of its arguments is a boolean, the result won't be a boolean.

Comment: @user2357112 ugh, sorry. Fixed.