# Setting python variable with conditional statement

Tags: python

I came across this line of code

```
ax = ax or plt.gca()
```

It is line 29 here

[https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/**init**.py](https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/__init__.py)

How exactly does this expression work?

Comment: There numerous tutorials on how Python `or` operator works. Google "python or operator."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange use of python's and / or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-pythons-and-or-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ax` will assume the result of the `or` operation between `ax` and result of `plt.gca()`
see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) for details.

#### Explaination

you can understand line 29 as a way to give a fallback value to `ax`,
if `ax` is passed as function parameter (so it's not `None`) passed value will be assigned to `ax`,
otherwise (`ax` is None) `plt.gca()` will be assigned to `ax`
because results of `None OR plt.gca()` is `plt.gca()` anything it will returns.

you can see line 29 as: `ax = ax if ax is not None else plt.gca()`

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of [line 29](https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/__init__.py#L29) of the code you refer to, `ax` is a function parameter that default to `None`.

```
def get_text_position(text, ax=None): #28
    ax = ax or plt.gca()              #29
    [...]                             #30
```

The assignment of `ax or plt.gca()` to `ax` is meant to ensure that the value of `ax` is not `None` for the remainder of the function scope. If the function is being called with a non-`None` value for the `ax` parameter, the line has no effect, as evaluation of the expression to the right stops at the `or`, which is already satisfied by its left operand not being `None`.
If no `ax` parameter gets passed to the function, or if it is explicitly set to `None`, evaluation of `ax or plt.gca()` results in the return value of the latter, as `ax`, being `None`, does not satisfy the expression, hence the remainder after the `or` must cover for it. [`matplotlib`'s documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca) indicates that its method that gets called in this case in line 29 will ensure to return a none-null object.

So long story short, the `or` operator is applicable not only to boolean operands, but works the same way with `None` and non-`None` values, as it does with `False` and `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If the first operand evaluates to `True`, the expression evaluates to the first operand:

```
>>> True or "second"
True

>>> "first" or "second"
"first"
```

If the first operand evaluates to `False`, the expression evaluates to the second operand:

```
>>> False or "second"
"second"

>>> 0 or "second"
"second"

>>> None or "second"
"second"
```

Here are some values that evaluate to the same as `False`:

```
False
0
None
""
[]
{}
```

---

So, in the line:

```
ax or plt.gca()
```

If `ax` is `None`, the expression evaluates to the second operand, `plt.gca()`.

```
>>> None or plt.gca()
plt.gca()
```