# Lambda function - Unknown number of arguments

Tags: python, function, lambda, expression, operands

Currently, this is how I resolve a "and" function using lambda with two arguments:

```
custom_function = lambda a, b: a and b
```

But how can I resolve an unknown number of arguments, like:

```
custom_function = lambda a, b, c, d, ...: what now?
```

Anybody had this issue before?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: BTW, the "all" builtin function just does that

Comment: @Don The `all` function does **not** do just that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "*args":

```
>>> custom_function = lambda *args: all(args)
>>> custom_function(1, 2, 3)
True
>>> custom_function(1, 2, 3, 0)
False
```

Which indeed is the same as just using "all":

```
>>> all(1, 2, 3)
True
>>> all(1, 2, 3, 0)
False
```

To be general, you can use "functools.reduce" to use any "2-parameters" function with any number of parameters (if their order doesn't matter):

```
import operator
import functools

c = lambda *args: functools.reduce(operator.and_, args)
```

(same results as before)

Comment: yea, but how can i map this to my lambda as i dont know the exact number of arguments?

Comment: @Creativecrypter *args means that you can pass any number of parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use [argument unpacking via the `*` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to process any number of arguments. You would have to resort to [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (Python2) or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (Python3) in order to combine them all with `and` in a single expression (as needed by the lambda):

```
from functools import reduce  # only Py3

custom_function = lambda *args: reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, args, True)
```

Note: this is not the same as [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), like many here suggest:

```
>>> all([1,2,3])
True
>>> 1 and 2 and 3
3
>>> custom_function(1,2,3)
3
```

Comment: and if would need to do "or" operation on unknown number of arguments?

Comment: You use `x or y` instead of `x and y` in the inner lambda.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `*args` to store an unknown number of arguments as a tuple.

Second, `all(args)` only return `Ture` or `False` but `and` operation may return value ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-pythons-and-or-operator) is why). So we need to use `reduce`.

Here is the solution:

```
custom_function = lambda *args: reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, args)
```

Test 1: arguments are Ture or False

```
>>> custom_function(True,False,True,False)
False
>>> custom_function(True,True,True)
True
```

Test 2: arguments are values

```
>>> custom_function(1,2,3,4,3,2)
2
>>> custom_function('a','b','d','s')
's'
```

Test 3: arguments are a combination of bool and values

```
>>> custom_function(1,2,True,4,3,2)
2
>>> custom_function(1,2,False,4,3,2)
False
```

Note the three tests are correct according to the definition of Logical **AND** (and):

> Return the first Falsey value if there are any, else return the last
>   value in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using the all function?

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = None
args = [a, b, c]
print (all(args))
# False
```