# startswith function - incorrect arguements - not throwing error

Tags: python, function, startswith

Can someone tell me why this doesn't throw an error?  It prints True when the user types in http:// and false when they type in https://.  I can't understand why it would work at all.

```
URL = input("Enter an URL address: ")
URL.startswith("http://" or "https://")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange use of "and" / "or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-and-or-operator)

Comment: We can say "starts with a or b" but what we mean by that is "starts with a or starts with b". Python needs the conditions rather explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"http://" or "https://"` is a boolean expression which evaluates to `"http://"`, because that's what an `or` statement is (because `"http://"` is the first True-ish value encountered in the `or` statement), you need to do this instead:

```
URL.startswith("http://") or URL.startswith("https://")
```

Also, as @ShadowRanger suggested, you could make this shorter and faster by passing a tuple of accepted starting strings to the `startswith` method, it will then return `True` if any of the strings in the tuple matched with the start of the string:

```
URL.startswith(("http://", "https://"))
```

Comment: There's a better way actually; [`startswith` also accepts a `tuple` of prefixes to check for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), and returns `True` if any of them match. So you could write `URL.startswith(("http://", "https://"))` and it would behave identically to the `or` separated version you wrote (just shorter to type, and faster to run).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Brilliant, I just added your note to my answer.