# Performing `and` between two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I accidentally ran following statement `[10] and [(3, True)]` and it gave back a result `[(3, True)`. As far as my understanding goes, this should have returned `True` because neither of the list is empty but to my surprise it didn't. Can someone help me understand this concept?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, and thanks for the link, I understood why it does so. It returns the result of the condition. I tried with `[] and [(1,False)]` and it resulted in `[]` which made me understand that the condition itself is returned.

Comment: @Prerit, check out this link, I think it answers your question quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007761/7087509. If you want to have a True/False value you need to explicitly cast it `bool([10] and [(3, True)])`