# using the "__and__" method in the abstract base int class

Tags: python, abstract-base-class

I am trying to understand the `__and__` method of the abstract base int Class. Here I have called the method two different ways. In nearly all cases, the two ways each behave as I expect, they output the second value, because both values are "truthy". But in the special case that the sum of the two numbers = -1, then the first way prints 0. Can anyone say why?

```py
value = -4
print(value.__and__(3)) # prints 0
print(value and 3)         # prints 3
```

Comment: What makes you say it's not bitwise AND?

Comment: And where did you get the idea of a "Number Class"? There's no Number class.

Comment: @user2357112: It's an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html).

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is not with the `__and__` operator. The bitwise operator in python is not `and` it's `&`:

```py
>>> (7).__and__(5) == (7 & 5)
True
```

As for how `and` interacts with non boolean values, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007761/1720199). For your particular case:

> `and` Returns the first Falsy value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.

In your case, both `-4` and `3` are non Falsy values, therefore the last value (`3`) is returned. Considering [what is considered Falsy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) we can also understand why `-4 and 0 and 3 == 0`, ie., because `0` is Falsy.

Note that this behavior for the `and` operator makes sense. It just extends the logic of the natural boolean and operator in the most natural way (or at least one of the most natural way). For example, `True and False and False and x`, will return `False` as soon as the first `False` is encountered, while `True and True and x` will simply return `x` as all previous boolean values validate the global statement.

Finally, the apparently strange behavior of the bitwise operator when dealing with negative numbers comes from [how negative numbers are encoded](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Two%27s_complement). Basically, to turn a positive number (eg, 4 = 000100) into a negative, you simply need to invert all it's bits (111011) then add 1 (111100 = -4). In the evaluating `3 & -4` is equivalent to solving the following:

```
  000011
& 111100
--------
= 000000
```

For the same reason `x & -4` will evaluate to `4` for any `x` in `4, 5, 6, 7` (the two low digits are always canceled by the terminating zeros in the binary representation of -4 (111100).

Comment: so, you are not sure why it is returning 0?

Comment: I can add that detail if that seems important to you :)

Comment: Now that I read my answer I wonder if you weren't talking about the `0` in  `print((-4).__and__(3))`. I should probably detail that case too, but maybe that wasn't your question?

Answer (score 0):

A classmate pointed out that the **and**() method uses "bitwise and". Not the normal AND. Also, I was using signed integers in my calculations instead of two's complement.