# Average returning a value even when list is empty

Tags: python, average

In Python a way to calculate the max of a list and output a value even with an empty list is to do this:

```
max(python_list, default=0)
```

Is there any similar way (in one statement and *obviously* without `try` and `except` or `if` and `else`) in Python to calculate the average?

I used this simple code:

```
average = sum(python_list)/ len(python_list)
```

and obviously I get this error with an empty list:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: What is the non-safe one?

Comment: If the list is empty, both `max` and average are undefined.  What did you want as a return value?  Simple code around an empty list the same way you did for your "average".

Comment: @EugeneSh., by safe I mean just one which does not output an error when the list is empty but it outputs a specific value.

Comment: @Prune, in one statement and without try and except?

Comment: Yes -- apply the same principles.  Post your code and the error you got.  What do you *want* to return for numerator and denominator?

Comment: `sum(python_list) / len(python_list) if python_list else default`

Comment: `average = np.mean(python_list)`

Comment: You can create a class that inherits from list and has a member method called `mean()`

Comment: See my edited post @DanielMesejo - I obviously knew about if and else in the same statement/line but they are still if and else.

Comment: How about `sum([x/len(lst) for x in lst])`? That has no conditions whatsoever. But has many divisions...

Comment: `sum(lst) / (len(lst) or 1)`

Comment: You could pretty easily write your own `average/mean` function that operates the same as `max` (with a default value), but why the restriction on `try/except` and `if/else`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, if this is actually right (it works but I have not see it again) then you should post as an answer so it is also reviewed.

Comment: As you can see in the link python core stats package raise an exception when the data list is empty. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f705f8e9b58955d0d9083e98d71ba01b2e69798c/Lib/statistics.py#L314

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and return a value in the except suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values/47007761#47007761) of the `or` operator on Truthy values, i.e. :

> Return the first Truthy value if there are any, else return the last
>   value in the expression.

You could do:

```
sum(lst) / (len(lst) or 1)
```

This will return `0` if the list `lst` is empty. Notice that is basically a [shortcut](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) for `val if val else default`.

Comment: This may a concise solution for what I ask for (upvote). In any case, it seems that python has neither a function for the average nor for an average which returns a default error as the max or min function.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit To the best of my knowledge there isn't one, at least in the standard library.

Comment: *nor for an average which returns a default value in case of error as the max or min function.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is:

```
sum([val/len(lst) for val in lst])
```

If the list is empty, nothing is divided by `len(lst)` (which is 0) so there are no errors. This will return 0 if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you consider that the answer is zero, I would do it this way, using the ternary operator:

```
avg = sum(lst) / len(lst) if lst else 0
```

That is a one-liner, at least.