# Logical operators in python strings

Tags: python, string

I know this question is too much basic, but I am unable to understand it.
For example, if have to search any of `N` words in a string, how can I do this. I tried logical operations.

```
('browser' or 'chrome') in 'start game'
```

It will return false.

```
('browser' or 'chrome') in 'start chrome'
```

It will return True.

```
('browser' or 'chrome') in 'start chrome'
```

This should return True, but it returns false. `chrome` word is in the string, so why it returns false.

```
('browser' and 'chrome') in 'start chrome'
```

This returns True. But why it returns true, even if only one word matches.

I want to return True, if even one-word matches, no matter at which index it is.

Comment: `('browser' or 'chrome')` evaluates to `'browser'`. You can use `if any(x in 'start chrome' for x in ('browser', 'chrome'))`

Comment: See [How do “and” and “or” act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Comment: any([a for a in ['browser',"chrome"] if a in 'start chrome'])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`('browser' or 'chrome')` evaluates to `'browser'`.

See [How do “and” and “or” act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

You can use [the `any` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x in 'start chrome' for x in ('browser', 'chrome')):
    # at least one of the words is in the string
```

and [the `all` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(x in 'start chrome' for x in ('browser', 'chrome')):
    # both words are in the string
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to compute `a or b`. The `or` operator works like this:

1. If `a` is truthy, return `a`
2. Otherwise, return `b`.

If you have more than two operands, for example, `a or b or c or d`, it's equivalent to `a or (b or (c or d))`, so it will work according to this algorithm:

1. If `a` is truthy, return `a`
2. Otherwise, if `b` is truthy, return `b`
3. Otherwise, if `c` is truthy, return `c`
4. Otherwise, return `d`.

So this expression: `('browser' or 'chrome') in 'start chrome'` will not work as you expect it to. First, `('browser' or 'chrome')` will evaluate to `'browser'` (because `'browser'` is truthy, as is any non-empty string), and `'browser' in 'start chrome'` is `False`.

What you might want to use is:

```py
('browser' in 'start chrome') or ('chrome' in 'start chrome')
```

Or you can use `any`, coupled with a generator comprehension:

```py
string = 'start chrome'
if any(substring in string for substring in ['browser', 'chrome', 'chromium']):
    print('Ta da!')
```

Or, if you really like `map`,

```py
if any(map(string.__contains__, ['browser', 'chrome', 'chromium'])):
    print('Ta da!')
```

Basically, `any` returns `True` if at least one element of the given iterable is `truthy`.

`a and b and c` works similarly to `or`:
1. If `a` is falsey, return `a`
1. Otherwise, if `b` is falsey, return `b`
1. Otherwise, return `c`

What you might want to use in place of your `and`-y expression is:

```py
('start' in 'start chrome') and ('chrome' in 'start chrome')
```

Or you can use `all`, which is like `any`, but implements `and`-logic instead or `or`-logic: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 0):

There's probably 2 approaches you could go with:
An easy, less dynamic approach:

```
"browser" in "start chrome" or "chrome" in "start chrome"
```

A longer but much more dynamic approach:

```
def OneContains(l, text):
    for i in l:
        if i in text:
            return True
    return False


print(OneContains(["browser","chrome"],"start chrome"))
```

Comment: I would rather use the `any` built-in instead or writing a loop.