# Using AND inside abs(number) in Python

Tags: python

Trying to understand how AND statement works inside `abs(numbers)` function.

Calling `print(abs(21-22 and 9-4 and 11-8))`

This would always give me whatever the last expression is. In this case it calculates 11-8, so it prints 3.
Why other expressions are not in the output and no error as well?

Comment: What did you *expect* from that? Why not just write `print(3)`? `a and b` is basically `b if a else a`.

Comment: and should be used in a truthy comparison

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the expression is inside an `abs` call doesn't change the way that it's interpreted:

```
>>> 21-22 and 9-4 and 11-8
3
```

which is of course the same as:

```
>>> -1 and 5 and 3
3
```

An `and` evaluates the "truthiness" of each operand.  If either of them is "falsey", that one is returned; otherwise the last one is returned.

All `int` values except `0` are "truthy", so the only time you'll get something other than the last value from an `and` of `int`s is if one of them is zero:

```
>>> -1 and 0 and 3
0
```

Comment: Yup. [The python docs explicitly state that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) `x and y` is equivalent to 'if x is false, then x, else y'

Answer (score 2):

`and` is a logical operator, it will return `True` if both the operands of the operator are true.

I believe the comma does what you expected to do in this case:

```
print(abs(21-22),abs(9-4),abs(11-8))
```