# How can I use conditionals in python to solve the code shown below?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, conditional-statements, password-checker

My intention is to create a user dictionary that contains 'username', 'password' and 'age' and to use conditions to test if an object outside what is in the dictionary will be accepted, just like a login page on a site. But I didn't get my desired result because of an error I made. What do I need to do to make the conditionals produce my desired results? And since dictionaries are mutable, what can I do to ensure the username and password are immutable?

```
user1 = {
  'username': 'Casper',
  'age': 26,
  'password': 'schism'
}

user2 = {
  'username': 'Stone',
  'age': 32,
  'password': 'kalamari'
}

user_name = input('What is your username: ')
pass_word = input('What is your password: ')

if user_name and pass_word == user1['username' and 'password']:
  print(' Your details are correct')

else:
  print('Incorrect details')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. Also please format your code.

Comment: `user_name and pass_word == user1['username' and 'password']` does not make sense, it doesn't evaluate the password part at all (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47007680/3001761 for why). Did you want `user_name == user1['username'] and pass_word == user1['password']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're asking about the ternary operator

Syntax :

```
[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]
```

Ans :

```
print("correct") if pass_word ==user1['password'] and user_name == user1['username'] else print("wrong")
```

Edit 1:

```
print("correct") if [pass_word,user_name] ==[user1['password'],user1['username']] else print("wrong")
```

You can do like this,but try to avoid writing like this,It reduces code readability

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, it worked just fine. How would you suggest i make it more readable?

Comment: This : print("correct") if pass_word ==user1['password'] and user_name == user1['username'] else print("wrong") and what do you mean by conditionals?

Comment: And what problem you're having? and please edit your question too so it will be clear