# Python range bitwise AND boundaries explanation

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, bitwise-and, boolean-algebra

i have a question on the bitwise AND output of two numbers.

> example: `print(A and B) = B`.
>
> `print(2 and 5) = 5`

Why is the bitwise AND of A, B = B? This is because this is different from expected result of say `0b110 & 0b111 = 6.`

Confused as to why A and B, where A and B are numbers outputs B.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `and` is logical. `&` is bitwise.

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values
This answers my question.
Thanks

Comment: This: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDOiQ.png

Comment: `and` and `or` *are not bitwise  operators*, they are logical operators. The correspond bitwise operators are `&` and `|`