# NumberCs and Conditional Operators

Tags: python, numbers, boolean, conditional-operator

I wrote a code like this:

```
print(1 and 9) #print 9
```

I thought that 1 evaluates to True and 9 evaluates to True as well. So `True and True` should be 1 right? But in here it is 9.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
The expression "x and y" first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its
value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value
is returned.
```

You can see it by help function too:

```
help("and")
```