# Python: integer.and(someType), integer.or(someType)

Tags: python

The following is valid Python (3.7.4) code:

```py
def f():
  return 1.and(0)
```

`dis.dis(f)` gives

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1.0)
              2 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP     6
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
        >>    6 RETURN_VALUE
```

This also works for or. Not and xor give SyntaxError. Generally, the structure for this expression seems to be `Integer.and(something)`, where something can be any type.

My interpretation of this is, that this is interpreted as a float with a logic operation as its decimal places.

[EDIT]

```py
a = 3
a.not(1)
```

yields a SyntaxError

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]
3.in(l)
```

yields True - I can see the purpose of this.
[/EDIT]

The question: **Why does this construct exist and what is its purpose (if any)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s spaced to look like a method call, but it’s actually a float literal, a binary operator, and redundant parentheses:

```
1.0 and 0
```

(related: [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values))

Float literals can end with a decimal point, and keywords don’t have to be separated by spaces as long as they can’t be mistaken for anything else.

```
>>> 1.
1.0
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense from the syntax perspective. I usually define my floats this way and stumbled across the above construct when VSCode suggested things to put behind the dot...