# Is this the right way to write OR in Python

Tags: python

Is this the correct usage of *or* in python: `if choice == 'N' or 'n':`

Or should it be `if choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':`

Comment: Definitely the second.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I rewrote the line as ```if choice == 'N' ``` and input ```n``` and it still came true. Does is mean that this ```==``` checks the value as case insenitive?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking @Debol. But comparisons *are* case sensitive. Your first code example will *always* return true — that's the problem with it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes I just noticed that. Why does this happen? How can I change it being always true?

Comment: That the way `or` works in python — it returns the first truthy value it sees. The string `n` is truthy.  You can verify with `print(choice == 'N' or 'n')`. See here for better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values

Comment: @MarkMeyer Even for ```if choice == 'N'``` it's returning true. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: You must have something else wrong. If you set `choice` to `n`. `choice == 'N'` is certainly false.