# None and logical operations and/or

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I was trying to fully understand the behavior of `None` as a boolean for logical `and` and `or` operations, so I tried the following code:

```py
for a, b in [(None, False), (None, True), (False, None), (True, None)]:
    print(f"{str(a):<5} & {str(b):<5}", a and b)

for a, b in [(None, False), (None, True), (False, None), (True, None)]:
    print(f"{str(a):<5} | {str(b):<5}", a or b)
```

That outputs:

```py
None  & False: None
None  & True : None
False & None : False
True  & None : None
None  | False: False
None  | True : True
False | None : None
True  | None : True
```

The last two cases of `and` are expected due to short-circuiting. If the first statement is `False` it returns `False` without checking the second one, while if the first one is `True` it directly returns the second one. But the first two cases show that `None` doesn't have any boolean value.

The last two cases of `or` are again expected due to short-circuiting. If the first statment is `False` it directly returns the second one, while if the first one is `True` it returns `True` without checking the second one. But the first two cases show that `None` has a negative boolean value.

I understand that the purpose of this negative value is to be able to do things like default values with `a = a or 5`, but why is it not consistent with the behavior shown for `and`? I was expecting both first `and` cases to return `False`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values). TL;DR: `and` returns the first **Falsy** value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression. `or` returns the first **Truthy** value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.

Comment: @Tomerikoo actually it does. I thought it returned `False` if there was a falsy value instead of returning the falsy value itself.

Answer (score 1):

> why is it not consistent with the behavior shown for and? I was expecting both first and cases to return False.

It's entirely consistent.

`and` returns the first operand if it's "falsy", otherwise the second; `or` returns the first operand if it's "truthy", otherwise the second. **Neither converts its operands to booleans**.

`None` is "falsy", since `and` returns the first operand if falsy `None and x` returns `None`, regardless of `x`.

Also your table is pretty confusing as `|` and `&` are actual Python operators (but not boolean operators, or short-circuiting).