# Difference between two ways of using 'or'

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, modulo

I am getting a different answers from these two pieces of code. I am confused about this. Why is **`i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0`** different from         **`i % 3 or i % 5 == 0`**?

```
>>>total = 0
>>>for i in range(1, 100):
>>>    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
>>>        total += i
...print(total)
```

```
>>>total = 0
>>>for i in range(1, 100):
>>>    if i % 3 or i % 5 == 0:
>>>        total += i
...print(total)
```

Comment: `i % 3` can be 0 or non 0. If it's a non-zero value, then it's true. So your expression will be equivalent to: `1 or i % 5 == 0` -> `True or whatever` -> `True`.

Comment: Python is not a natural language...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Comment: Thank u I got it from my friend.

Comment: When we use -> if i % 3 or i % 5 == 0:  it means i % 3 is not equal to 0 or i % 5 is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about it like this (using parentheses):

```
>>>total = 0
>>>for i in range(1, 100):
>>>    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
>>>        total += i
...print(total)
```

You are checking first if `i%3 == 0` and then if `i%5 == 0`. In the second example you are checking if `i % 3` is true or `i % 5 == 0`. Hopefully, you see that there is a big difference

Comment: When we use -> if i % 3 or i % 5 == 0:  it means i % 3 is not equal to 0 or i % 5 is equal to zero.