# Python: insert 68 empty strings into a list

Tags: python

I am extracting values from excel into a list but some of them are blank.

I want to check if the list is empty, and if empty insert 68 empty strings. Is there a way to do that?

```
a = []

if not a:
   #enter 68 empty strings into a. eg: a = ['', '', '',....]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python lets you multiply a list with a number to repeat it:

```
a = [''] * 68
```

If you also have other references to this list, so you actually need to update the same list instead of creating an new one, use `extend`:

```
a.extend([''] * 68)
```

Comment: short and quick

Answer (score 2):

Using the [logical `or` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values), you can avoid conditions to create the list with empty strings, or keep the original list in case it was not empty:

```py
a = a or [''] * 68
```

- If `a` is empty, then it's *falsey* so the `or` will return the second argument.
- If `a` is not empty, it is *truthy* so the `or` will return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []

if not a:
   a.extend(["" for _ in range(68)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list a, and we want to insert n=68 blank strings at position i

```
a = [1, 2]
i = 1
n = 68
result = a[:i] + [''] * n + a[i:]
```

Then of course you can set a = result if you wanted to modify a directly. This is of course overkill, as you don't really want to insert into an existing list, this time, but I thought I'd answer the question asked.