# "Not in" operator doesn't take "or" operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this little python code, it doesn't work as below.

```
while True:
    activity = input("What would you like to do today? ")
    a="cinema"
    b="tennis"
    if a or b not in activity.lower():
        print(f"Instead of {activity} I want to go to the cinema")
    else:
        print("Sure Let's do that!!")
```

However when I extract the `or b` , it works fine

```
while True:
    activity = input("What would you like to do today? ")
    a="cinema"
    b="tennis"
    if a  not in activity.lower():
        print(f"Instead of {activity} I want to go to the cinema")
    else:
        print("Sure Let's do that!!")
```

The question is why doesn't `a or b` doesn't when used with `not in` work?

EDIT: I have done the below modification, But still doesn't work.

```
while True:
    activity = input("What would you like to do today? ")
    a="cinema"
    b="tennis"
    if (a not in activity.lower()) or (b not in activity.lower()):
        print(f"Instead of {activity} I want to go to the cinema")
    else:
        print("Sure Let's do that!!")
```

Below link is also suggested for this post. It is also very good. So I share it for the ones who will benefit from

[How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: You must write it fully as "a not in activity.lower() or b not in activity.lower()".

Comment: `or` *never* works this way. Python != English

Comment: Admittedly, creating `not in` as a separate operator compared to `not (x in y)` migh make it seem so...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure I get that now. What we need to think is as True or False in this case. Hope I am right?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks the answers are amazing at the link.

Comment: Also, the relevant section of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: "EDIT: I have done the below modification, But still doesn't work." The reason this one doesn't work is a simple logical error. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, it's not doing what you think:

```
if a or b not in activity.lower():
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
if (a) or (b not in activity.lower()):
```

Which means something different, and will be `True` as long as `a` is not null or empty. Besides you have the comparison backwards, the correct syntax you're looking for is:

```
if activity.strip().lower() not in (a, b):
```

Comment: The syntax you gave doesn't work either. I guess this many operators doesn't work in python.

Comment: Your answer explains a lot though

Comment: `if activity.lower() not in (a,b)`: works too, and is less verbose.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yep, you're right. I didn't realize that OP has the comparison  backwards. Thank you, I've updated my answer!

Comment: @ÇağlarYıldız it's not a problem with the number of operators :) is just that you had the comparison backwards. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I also updated the question, can you tell what is wrong?

Comment: Mmm in the case of `in` strings don't act like a container of characters, because `in` checks if one string is a substring of another

Comment: The version you had originally would work for things like `activity = "the cinema"` since `a in activity.lower()` will give true since it is a substring, the version you took from @MarkTolonen only works when the input is the same.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that wasn’t from me. See the 3rd comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the value of `a or b`:

```
>>> a = "cinema"
>>> b = "tennis"
>>> a or b
'cinema'
```

The "or" operator doesn't have a special different meaning when it's part of an `in`.

Comment: While it's true that `or` works this way, the operator precedence is not what you expect. For example, if you add `c = {'cinema'}`, then `a or b not in c` results in `'cinema'` (the same as `a or (b not in c)`, whereas `(a or b) not in c` results in `False`.

Answer (score 0):

`a or b not in c` is treated as `(a) or (b not in c)`.  `a` is considered True if it is non-zero or non-empty.  So if a is a non-empty string, `a or b not in c` will always be True.

`c not in (a,b)` is what you want.  It tests that the value of c is not a member of the container, equivalent to `c != a and c != b`.

In your edit, `activity` is a string, and `in` in strings works more like **contains**.  So this code:

```
activity = "run"
a="cinema"
b="tennis"
if (a not in activity.lower()) or (b not in activity.lower()):
```

is equivalent to:

```
'cinema' not in 'run' or 'tennis' not in 'run'
```

which is:

```
True or True  # result True
```

Note `'tennis' in 'thetennisball'` is `True` because `'thetennisball'` *contains* the word `'tennis'`.  If you are looking for exact matches this isn't what you want.

Another issue is using `or`.  When testing that a thing is not one thing or another, one of them will always be false, since a thing can't be two things at once.  You'll never get a True for `x != 2 or x != 1` for example.  If x is 1 it is not 2 and if x is 2 it is not 1. Use `and` instead.

To test for words in an exact list of words, use a list (or other container like tuple):

```
'tennis' not in ('cinema','tennis') # False
```

Comment: The only part I don't understand is about my edit. You say tennis="run" but in the "tennis" !="r" part you claim it is going to search for each letter.  That surely returns false. Doesn't it search as a whole container?

Comment: @ÇağlarYıldız Actually, I misspoke.  *string* in *string* works differently.  `'def' in 'abcdefghi'` returns True.  `in` for strings is more like *contains*.  I'll edit the answer to correct that, but still not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

First, it is checking `if (a) or (b not in activity.lower())` This is not right. What you want is something to check for a string in a string like `if activty.count(a) == 0 and activty.count(b) == 0` becuase this checks how many times a and b appear in activity.

Comment: Thanks I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Sadly, if (a not in activity.lower()) or (b not in activity.lower()):-> didn't work

Comment: `activity` is a string and `in` won't return True unless `a` is a single character matching a character of `activity`.

Comment: you should try `if activity.find(a) == -1 and activity.find(b) == -1` becuase this will find a string inside a string

Comment: or you could use this `if activity.count(a) == 0 and activity.count(b) == 0` it checks how many times `a` and `b` appear inside of activity