# How to evaluate logical operaters within a print statement

Tags: python, printing, logical-operators

I came across a couple of questions asking me to predict the output of code that looks like this:

```
a=5
b=6 
print ((a and b) or (a>b))
```

I am not quiet sure how to make sense out of that :(
Here's another one.
Could someone please help me out ?

```
a=4
b=6
c=10
print((a<=b) and print(c) ((c==a) and (not(c<b))))
```

Edit: got a couple of comments saying the syntax is wrong, hence i attached a picture of the original question...

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is valid python syntax.

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you unsure how operations like `and` and `or` work? Are you asking about the order of evaluation?

Comment: I predict that your first example will result in a syntax error and your second example will produce a TypeError exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Answer (score 1):

you can run following code to see the output.

```
x = 10
print(x > 5 and x < 15)

#This returns True because 10 is greater than 5 AND 10 is less than 15.


#or
x = 10
print(x > 5 or x < 2)

#This returns True because one of the conditions are true.
#10 is greater than 5, but 10 is not less than 2.


#not
x = 10
print(not(x > 5 and x < 15))
#This returns False because not reverses the result of and.
```

you can not call print function in a print function.
Click [here for more info](https://libguides.ntu.edu.sg/python/logicalop)

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors, so I'll assume the following

##### code 1

```
a=5
b=6 
print ((a and b) or (a>b))
```

*NB. I added the missing parenthesis*

This will print `6` as both `a` and `b` evaluate as Truthy, so the operation evaluates as `b`. The condition after `or` is not evaluated since `a and b` is True.

##### code 2

```
a=4
b=6
c=10
print((a<=b) and print(c) or ((c==a) and (not(c<b))))
```

*NB. I added the missing operator, I chose `or` as it's more interesting*

This should return:

```
10
False
```

`(a<=b)` evaluates as `b` ; `print(c)` prints 10 and evaluates as `None` (which evaluates as False), so this whole first part `(a<=b) and print(c)` evaluates as `None`/`False`. This leads to the right-hand part or the `or` to be evaluated: `(c==a)` is `False`, so the whole thing evaluates as `False`, which is printed as the final output.

Comment: With True, do you mean true or `True`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode it was actually `False` :p (or rather Falsy), and Truthy for the first code