# Python: justification for boolean operators (and, or) not returning booleans

Tags: python, boolean, language-design, comparison-operators

[EDIT: this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values); I am asking a question of language design, i.e. why it is this way in the first place. I am not confused about **how** it behaves, I am confused about **why** this behavior was decided upon in the first place.]

In Python (and some other languages, e.g. Lua), the boolean operators `and` and `or` do not return boolean values `True` and `False` as one might expect, but rather:

- `x or y`: if `x` is falsey, then `y`, otherwise `x`
- `x and y` if `x` is falsey, then `x`, otherwise `y`

It is easy to see that in the special case where `x` and `y` are booleans this behaves as expected.

My question is, what is the actual justification for generalizing in this way? I know that you can use it for tricks like:

```
foo = x or None
```

Or a DIY ternary operator like:

```
foo = x and y or z
```

But I don't feel as though these are strong enough justifications for such a surprising behavior. Whenever I see the non-boolean return value being relied on for its actual value (rather than in an if statement or something, where it doesn't matter either way), I always have to double-check my understanding of it since I always forget how it works and I need to look it up again. I would usually prefer it written in a more verbose way. Is there a **fundamental reason** why it should work this way, or is it really just for tricks?

Comment: Some of us find it useful and are not confused by it. I'm not sure what makes those examples "tricks" and not just uses. Perhaps you might get used to it and find it less surprising.

Comment: This is normal behaviour in python. For non-bool values like list or str, Get more information [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-boolean-operation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Comment: @khwelwood I consider them tricks because it allows for a minor reduction in character count (compared to the ternary operator) at the cost of a huge reduction in legibility. It seems useful for code golfing and little else.

Comment: @tbhaxor I am fully aware of **how** truthiness and falsiness work in Python. My question is **why** these specific operators work in this way. My question is about language design, not behavior.

Comment: There wasn't always a ternary operator in Python. There wasn't even always a boolean type in Python. You think they are tricks because you find them difficult to read; but that's purely subjective.

Comment: The "DIY ternary" trick has always been a bad idea - if `y` is falsy, you end up with `z`.

Comment: "that's purely subjective" -- this proves too much; you can use it to gainsay practically anything. a core tenet of Python's language design is readability and ease of teaching. suppose you were teaching python and a student asks: but **why** does it act this way? what do you tell that person?

Comment: "you can use it to gainsay practically anything"—No, only subjective things like your finding something a "huge reduction in legibility" that others find not at all a reduction in legibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python's case, the `bool` type didn't even exist until over a decade after the language was released. If it had existed from the start, perhaps `and` and `or` would have been defined differently. But, as is, backward compatibility was far more important. From [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) that introduced the type:

> Another consequence of the compatibility requirement is that the expression "True and 6" has the value 6, and similarly the expression "False or None" has the value None. The "and" and "or" operators are usefully defined to return the first argument that determines the outcome, and this won't change; in particular, they don't force the outcome to be a bool. Of course, if both arguments are bools, the outcome is always a bool. It can also easily be coerced into being a bool by writing for example "bool(x and y)".

EDIT: BTW, at its start, Python was intended to "bridge the gap" between programming in "data-rich" languages like `C` and "convenient" languages like Unixy shells (`sh`, `csh`, etc). Python's `and` and `or` were more like `&&` and `||` act in shell languages, consuming - left to right - all and only the operands needed to resolve whether the overall chain succeeded ("true") or failed ("false").

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` are value selectors not value creators. You can use the resolved value of a chain of operators without knowing which operation determined the result. How useful is it? That's debatable. Selecting a default value `value or default` and simple if-then-else `condition and foo or bar` (before the ternary operator of course) are familiar.

Python doesn't actually know what's going to happen to the object right after the object has been resolved. Maybe it will be a test `if foo or bar:` and `bool()` (or its C equivant) will be called. Maybe it will be used as an instance `(foo or bar).baz()` or will be added to something `(val or 100) + 10`. The point is, its the next step in the program that decides. Why would you convert it to a boolean when you don't know what happens next?

Since interim resolved objects already hold the "truthiness" of the in-progress operation, python can simply pass the object to the next stage of processing as seen in this disassembly. When the chain completes and python has jumped to the line marked ">>", the right thing is already in the register for the operation.

```
>>> def foo(a,b):
...     return (a or b or 100) + 10
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     10
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     10
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
        >>   10 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least one compelling reason: it lets you define custom boolean types that use `and` and `or`. Here is an example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CoolBool:
    value: bool
    note: str

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value

    def answer(self):
        return "Yes" if self else "No"


print(CoolBool(False, "foo") or CoolBool(True, "bar"))
# -> CoolBool(value=True, note='bar')
```

Maybe a string note isn’t particularly useful, but I think being able to define methods on a boolean-like class probably is.

Comment: It's very hard to call this a compelling reason. The example is contrived, and in practice, classes that want to do anything interesting with boolean operations use `&` and `|`, because `and` and `or` aren't overloadable.