# Selecting specific values out of a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column, 'state', that has the values 'failed', 'successful', and two or three other values.

I am trying to create a dataframe with only the rows that contain 'failed' and 'successful' in the 'state' column.

I have implemented the following code:

```
df = df[df['state'].str.contains('failed' or 'successful', na = False)]
```

but I am only receiving 'failed' rows, not 'successful'.

Any suggestions? I have used this same format on other datasets with success

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the expression `"failed" or "successful"` evaluates to `"failed"` since the non-empty string `"failed"` is truthy. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values) to learn why this happens.

What you really need to do is evaluate the column on 2 conditions: `str.contains("failed")` and `str.contains("successful")` and combine those results together. You can do this using the `|` operator on the dataframes.

```py
df[df["state"].str.contains("failed", na=False) | df["state"].str.contains("successful", na=False)]
```

**EDIT:** As Henry mentioned below, you can get a more succinct answer using regex with `df.str.contains`.

```py
df[df["state"].str.contains("failed|success", na=False)]
```

Comment: Just regex OR might be better here: `df[df["state"].str.contains("failed|success", na=False)]`

Comment: Thank you rchome and Henry! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

because `("failed" or "successful") == "failed"`, check the short circuit behavior doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).