# To find words starting with vowels

Tags: python

I am trying to pickout the words that start with vowels from given list. I am having issue when the starting letter of word is a capital vowel. I am trying below code, can anyone explain why I am not getting desired output.

```
l=["wood", "old", 'Apple', 'big','item', 'euphoria']
p=[]
for i in l:
    if i[0] in('aeiou' or 'AEIOU'):
        p.append(i)
print(p)
```

Comment: Try `print('aeiou' or 'AEIOU')` to understand why this code does not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `('aeiou' or 'AEIOU')` evaluates to just `'aeiou'`. Thus you end up testing for lower case vowels only. For the reason, see [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values)

Instead, you wanted to say

```
if i[0] in 'aeiou' or i[0] in 'AEIOU':
```

or

```
if i[0] in 'aeiouAEIOU':
```

or

```
if i.lower() in 'aeiou':
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be easier to use `lower()` like so

```
l=["wood", "old", 'Apple', 'big','item', 'euphoria']
p=[]
for i in l:
    if i[0].lower() in('aeiou'):
        p.append(i)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
['old', 'Apple', 'item', 'euphoria']
```