# code expects 4 values and only gets 3 even though i have 4 values connect to it

Tags: python

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import keyboard
import threading

threads = []

play_num = input('are you playing as player (1) or (2)> ')

def get_img(player_num):
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    if player_num == '1':
        b1 = image.getpixel((246, 144))
        b2 = image.getpixel((426, 151))
        b3 = image.getpixel((591, 136))
        b4 = image.getpixel((761, 151))
        return b1 and b2 and b3 and b4
    elif player_num == '2':
        b1 = image.getpixel((1161, 151))
        b2 = image.getpixel((1325, 164))
        b3 = image.getpixel((1489, 128))
        b4 = image.getpixel((1671, 149))
        return b1 and b2 and b3 and b4
    else:
        quit()


def arrow_one(color_index):
    if not color_index[0] == 255:
        pass
    else:
        keyboard.press('a')
        keyboard.release('a')

def arrow_two(color_index):
    if not color_index[0] == 255:
        pass
    else:
        keyboard.press('s')
        keyboard.release('s')

def arrow_tree(color_index):
    if not color_index[0] == 255:
        pass
    else:
        keyboard.press('d')
        keyboard.release('d')

def arrow_four(color_index):
    if not color_index[0] == 255:
        pass
    else:
        keyboard.press('f')
        keyboard.release('f')


def stop_code():
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a' and 'c'):
        print('gg')
        quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            while True:
                color1, color2, color3, color4 = get_img(play_num)
                for _ in range(1):
                    stop_check = threading.Thread(target=stop_code())
                    step1 = threading.Thread(target=arrow_one(color1))
                    step2 = threading.Thread(target=arrow_two(color2))
                    step3 = threading.Thread(target=arrow_tree(color3))
                    step4 = threading.Thread(target=arrow_four(color4))
                    step1.start()
                    step2.start()
                    step3.start()
                    step4.start()
                    stop_check.start()
                    threads.append(step1 and step2 and step3 and step4 and stop_check)

                for thread in threads:
                    thread.join()
        else:
            pass
```

Each funtion goes through to check if its pixel is white or not, and if its not white, it presses the button accordingly

the get_img fucntion is what gets all the colors and returns b1, b2, ect...,
It shows that its expecting 4 (becuase i have 4 things connected to it), however I get the error:

**ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)**

but I clearly have 4 values being returned and im completly stumped, i would appreciate any help given.

Comment: You are expected to return 4 distinct variables `return b1, b2, b3, b4` within the function `get_img()`

Comment: BTW, `threads.append(a and b and c and d and e)`  does not do what you want. It'll be identical to either `threads.append(e)` or `threads.append(None)` (potentially substituting some other falsey value in place of `None`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not English.  To return a tuple of 4 values use `b1,b2,b3,b4` not `b1 and b2 and b3 and b4`.  In Python `and` is a logical-AND so the result is the last value if all the values are "truthy" (True, non-zero and non-empty objects are "truthy"), and the first "falsey" value if any values are "falsey" (False, zero and empty objects are "falsey").

Example:

```py
>>> b1,b2,b3,b4 = 1,2,0,3
>>> b1 and b2 and b3 and b4    # not all values are non-zero
0
>>> b1,b2,b3,b4 = 1,2,3,4      # result is last value since all are non-zero
>>> b1 and b2 and b3 and b4
4
>>> b1,b2,b3,b4                # A tuple of 4 values (what you want)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

See [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007761/235698) for more information.