# Stuck in loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I made a function, but when I run it, it's stuck in the loop:

```
def valid_word(words):
    word= random.choice(words)
    while "-" or " " in word:
        word= random.choice(words)
        print("Inside loop")
    return word.upper()
```

Comment: You have `"-" or (" " in word)`, which is always true.

Comment: `while "-" or " " in word` -> `while "-" in word or " " in word`

Comment: @khelwood, please, add also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47007680/4046632

Comment: I tried while "-" in word or " " in word but its still stuck in loop, is there something wrong with the list?

Comment: How do we know what the list is?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QSCn9CNg

Comment: this is the list