# Use of AND & OR in the same LAMBDA function

Tags: python, lambda, logical-operators

I have been going through a tutorial on lambda functions and came across this line of code to evaluate if a number is odd or even. And I do not understand how the tow logic operators work in this function.

```
(lambda x: (x % 2 and 'odd' or 'even'))(5)
```

> > > 'odd'

A more "usual/readable" way of doing it might be:

```
(lambda x: 'even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd')(3)
```

> > > 'odd'

I do understand that x % 2 will return either 1 or 0 (truthy or falsey) and based on that the ensuing logic will work. What I do not understand is how the output of x % 2 is then used in the body of the function and how it computes if it is 'odd' or 'even' that is returned. It might have something to do with the priority of Pythonic operators but so far it is not very clear. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note the definitions of `and` and `or` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: `x or y` means "if x is true, then x, else y". `x and y` means "if x is false, then x, else y". From that, can you see how the lambda expression in the question works?

Comment: For the first lambda function, you should take a look at truthy and falsy values. What happens when you use `and`, `or` with values beyond `True` or `False` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values. The second line is a basic one line conditional.

Comment: this has nothing to do with lambda expressions, this is just how the `or` and `and` operators work. Note, lambda expressions aren't anything special - they add no real functionality, they are equivalent to `def _lambda(<args>): return <expression>` just that no name gets assigned to, and they are expressions, not statements

Comment: Anyway, this works due to precedence, since it is equivalent to ` (x % 2 and "odd") or "even"` and the way that `and`/`or` work (evaluating to one of it's operands). But note, this is potentially buggy, because of `"odd"` were soething falsey, e.g. the empty string, `""` this breaks, which is why you should use a conditional expression instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Rule

In Python, conjunctions (stuff joined with 1 or more `and`) and disjunctions (`or`) evaluate to the **last** operand that needs to be evaluated to determine the truthiness of the whole expression.
If there is no short-circuit operand, that is the last operand of the expression.

#### Conjunctions

For `and`, this determining operand is the first falsy operand (after which it is clear that the whole expression will falsy).

#### Disjunctions

For `or`, this determining operand is the first truthy operand (after which it is clear that the whole expression will truthy).

#### Your case:

The expression in your example is scoped:

```
(n % 2 and "odd") or "even"
```

Odd:

```
(1 and "odd") or "even"
# conj: both operands truthy, so the last one is taken
"odd" or "even"
# disj: first operand is truthy, so short-circuit
"odd"
```

Even:

```
(0 and "odd") or "even"
# conj: first operand is falsy, so short-circuit
0 or "even"
# disj: first operand falsy, so last operand is taken regardless of its value
"even"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python [every object can be tested for its boolean value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) - I highly recommend reading the linked Python official documentation section.
Python [`and` and `or` operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) not only evaluate the expression, but also return one of the operands based on the Boolen value:

- `and` returns the **second operand** if the first evaluates to `True`; otherwise the first operand (evaluated to `False`) is returned.

```
>>> 1 and ''
''
>>> {} and True
{}
```

- `or` returns the **first operand** if it evaluates to `True`; otherwise the second operand is returned.

```
>>> 'text' or True
'text'
>>> None or 0
0
```

In your lambda expression `x % 2`returns `1` for odd numbers, that in turn evaluates to Boolean `True`. Hence the first `and` operator returns the `'odd'` string (first point in the list above), which becomes the first argument of the `or` operator. Because in Python non-empty strings are considered `True`, according to the second list point `or` returns this value (`'odd'`) immediately.
By the same token, for even numbers `x % 2` equates to `0` that is considered `False` in Python. So `0` is returned by the first `and` operator immediately, and then effectively discarded by the second `or` operator, which in turn returns its second operand, the `'even'` string.

Take-home exercise: explain for the result of the following expression

```
(lambda x: (x % 2 and '' or 'even'))(5)
```

and why it is always the same regardless of the function argument, where the `'odd'` string has been replaced with empty `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Odd Even using Lambda Expression:

```
listing = [lambda a=x: a*2 if a%2==0 else -a for x in range(1,11)]
for item in listing:
    print(item())
```

If your want to change into list data type to above function then you can implement this code:

```
listing = [lambda a=x: a*2 if a%2==0 else -a for x in range(1,11)]
for item in listing:
    print(item())                        
a = []
for item in listing:
   a.append(item())
print(a)
```