# use more than one logical condition in np.fromfunction()

Tags: numpy, conditional-statements

I'm relatively new to programming. As a physics teacher i'm trying to learn python because I wan't to offer the children introduction lesson's in coding. At the moment I am studying arrays. As a practice for myself I tried to create the levi-Cita-tensor with np.fromfunction(). It doesn't seem to accept more than one logical condition, the problem is probably related to the different nature of arrays as opposed to lists, but I don't understand what exactly is going wrong.

I wrote a function to check if two or three of the indices are the same (return 0), if not if the indices are cyclic (return 1), or anti-cyclic (return -1). When using the function in np.fromfunction() I've got:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Instead of boring the people on this site with my probably not so elegantly written function ;) I tried a simpler command to test the use of logical conditions in np.fromfunction():

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j, k: i == j, (3,3,3), dtype=int)
```

which returns an array with boolean data

But if I use two logical conditions, for example:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j, k: i==j or j==k, (3,3,3), dtype=int)
```

I get the same valueError as with my original function. I am probably not understanding the concept of vectorizing correctly. In my understanding of the process, the computer starts at the position i=0, j=0, k=0, performs the two logical conditions en returns the truthvalue at position i=0, j=0, k=0. It seems to work that way with only one logical condition, why not with two (or more as used in my original function.

Comment: `(i==j) | (j==k)` is needed to use 2 logical tests with arrays.

Comment: you get that value error when trying to use arrays in an expression that only works for scalar values.  Such as `if` and `or`.  `fromfunction` passes arrays to your lambda.  Look at its code.  And read  its docs with care, rather than 'hope'.

Comment: I don't think `numpy` is a good thing to include in intro coding lessons.  Good programming habits, including reading the docs, debugging, etc can be learned with basic python.   Including numpy requires an added level of abstraction, sort of like vectors and rotating coordinate systems in a physics lesson.

Comment: Searching SO for `[numpy] fromfunction`, gives 70 results.  People have been complaining about poor documenation for the function for a decade.  But I suspect the underlying problem is wishful thinking, not the documenation itself.  It's too easy to think, "this is what I want to do for each cell", and hope from the name that it will magically apply that function across the whole index range.  IMO `np.fromfunction` is nearly useless.  Read the numpy basic docs instead: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the website! Thank you for the well thought-out question!

Unfortunately, the docs (in my opinion) aren't so great for `np.fromfunction`. What I think we would both expect is that it is implemented something like:

```
arr = np.empty(shape)
for i, j, k in indices:
    arr[i, j, k] = your_func(i, j, k)
```

This means that `your_func` is executed as many times as there are triplets of indices.

However, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1776-L1845), it is implemented more like:

```
i, j, k = np.indices(shape)
arr = your_func(i, j, k)
```

That means that `your_func` is only called once, not with scalars, but with tensors filled with every `i`, `j`, and `k`. What does that look like? Try `np.fromfunction` with `print`:

```
>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i, j, k: print(f"{i!r}\n{j!r}\n{k!r}"), (3, 3, 3), dtype=int)
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]]])
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

Which are exactly the arrays that [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) returns.

As a result, the input function to `np.fromfunction` needs to be able to handle full arrays as input, and `or`-ing two arrays doesn't work!

---

I would recommend staying away from `np.fromfunction`, even if you manage to vectorize your code. Instead, you may be able to use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (hint: use `np.indices` directly with `sparse=True`) to make your code even better.

Instead, you could also iterate over all of the indices and call your function more than once like in the initial pseudocode!

---

Why can't we `or` two numpy arrays?

This is due to a limitation in python. When you write `a or b`, python checks if `a` is "Truthy" (i.e. by calling `bool(a)`), and then returns `a` if the check is `True`, and `b` otherwise. This behavior is known as short-circuiting and can lead to [some useful tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values).

So when `a` and `b` are numpy arrays, python calls `bool` on `a`, and numpy responds with the fact that the truth value (or "truthyness") of an array is ambiguous. That makes sense, because how should an array filled with both `True` and `False` be treated? ;)

Thankfully, numpy implemented a function ([`np.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)) to replicate the desired behavior. For boolean arrays, the "bitwise or" operator `|` also works like this. But you have to take care to parenthesize your expressions due to operator precedence, as hpaulj does in his comment.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Seaching SO for '[numpy] fromfunction' shows that this function has been misunderstood for a long time. I suspect it's more a problem with wishful thinking than the documentation itself.  The source code is incredibly simple, much shorter than the documenation, old or rewritten, implies.

All it does it generate some index arrays, and pass them to your function.  There's no magical "vectorization" or cell-by-cell iteration.  That action, if any has to be builtin  to your own function.

`indices` makes an array:

```
In [94]: np.indices((2,3))
Out[94]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

`meshgrid` or `mgrid` could have been used instead.

Let's unpack that array into two (basic python functionality):

```
In [95]: I,J = np.indices((2,3))
In [96]: I,J
Out[96]: 
(array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]))
```

So we now have two (or in your example 3) arrays.  We can do all kinds of calculations with these.  See numpy basics documentation for get some ideas.

For example we could do `I+J`.  But following your case, we can compare them:

```
In [97]: I==J
Out[97]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

The result is boolean array of the same shape.  That ability to do element-by-element comparison is builtin to the compiled methods of numpy arrays.  Here they match in shape, but `broadcasting` adds some magic that allows us to work, within limits, on arrays with different shapes.

But if I try to use 2 tests, I get the 'ambiguity' error:

```
In [98]: I==J or J>0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[98], line 1
----> 1 I==J or J>0

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

That's a separate issue from `fromfunction`, though fairly frequent.  We get such an error when trying to use arrays in a python context that expects scalar boolean values.  An `if` clause is a classic case, but here it's the `or` - which has an underlying `if` that tries to short circuit.

What we have to do instead is use () to control precidence, and `|` to perform a element-wise logical operation.

```
In [99]: (I==J) | (J>0)
Out[99]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]])
```

In good numpy code we  try to use the compiled methods that work with whole arrays.  That may require a shift in thinking.  So times we want to do things that can only be expressed in scalar terms

Thinking in those terms:
In [100]: def foo(i,j):
...:        if (j>0) or (i==j):
...:            return True
...:        else:
...:            return False
...:

and using a nest list comprehension:

```
In [101]: [[foo(i,j) for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
Out[101]: [[True, True, True], [False, True, True]]
```

Trying to apply our `indices` arrays to this function produces the ambiguity error:

```
In [102]: foo(I,J)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[102], line 1
----> 1 foo(I,J)

Cell In[100], line 2, in foo(i, j)
      1 def foo(i,j):
----> 2        if (j>0) or (i==j):
      3            return True
      4        else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

There is a function to apply arrays to such a scalar function, though I'm somewhat hesitant to demonstate it, since it is frequently misused as well,

```
In [103]: np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[bool])(I,J)
Out[103]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]])
```

Its documenation, including a performance disclaimer, is a bit clearer.

Sorry, this has gotten a lot longer than I intended, but hopefully there's something useful here.