# a question about python assignment statment with 'or' and 'xml.Elementree.Element'

Tags: python

I'm parsing a .xml file, the tag name of the file has same structure except some uses CamelCase and other uses lowercase. So I write code like `et = data.find('productid') or data.find('productId')` to get value.
But I get `None` in the end.

Then I found if change the order, it's ok.
I suspect that the mechanism of Element() is related or `or` can only be used for basic types.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> e=ElementTree.Element('root')
>>> a = e or None
>>> a
>>> a = None or e
>>> a
<Element 'root' at 0x10abb26b0>
>>>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] of the problem. The code you provided only demonstrates that the trivial scenario works as you expect.

Comment: ```a = None or e``` does not do what you think it does.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Comment: @ewokx That seems irrelevant…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do "and" and "or" act with non-boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/how-do-and-and-or-act-with-non-boolean-values). Btw, I was a bit surprised `ElementTree.Element('root')` is considered falsy in this case, but I guess it being an empty root makes sense (I now see the reference to docs in @deceze answer)

Answer (score 1):

> Caution: Elements with no subelements will test as `False`. Testing the truth value of an Element is deprecated and will raise an exception in Python 3.14. Use specific `len(elem)` or `elem is None` test instead.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element

So your `e` is *falsey*. So the expression `e or None` works like `False or None`, which will [return the second operand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47007680/476) `None`, as both are falsey. Conversely `None or e` will return the second operand `e`.

Comment: thank your clearly anwser.