# How short circuit code works in python

Tags: python

This looks like a short circuit way of writing code but I just can't understand it. Is there a specific way to read this kind of short circuit.

e.g:
`n = n and int(n)`
`n = n or int(n)`

Comment: @vaultah - This is a not operator question. I meant to understand short circuit version here.

Comment: Answers on that page explain the behaviour of the `and` operator perfectly, you just need to apply them to your code.

Comment: that's correct but I dont understand how n and int(n)..is working here. How this expression is being evaluated?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19187401/2301450) answer, `x and y` means *"if x is false, then x, else y"*. Substitute *x* for `n` and *y* for `int(n)`.

Comment: Thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

`and` conditions return the last truthy value or the first falsy one. So if `n` is falsy, `n` will remain whatever value it was. If `n` is truthy, it will be cast to an `int`.

Comment: this makes sense.  so n = n or int(n) would mean that whatever n would evaluate to ( if n is true or false), next expression int(n) won't be evaluated (it would be skipped)?