# Python - logical evaluation order with grouping and without grouping

Tags: python

Can anybody please explain the behavior when is False preferred over None or None over False

```
1 in None or []  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-0f48647a1d09>", line 1, in <module>
    1 in None or []
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
1 in (None or [])
Out[5]: False

1 in (None or [1])
Out[6]: True

1 in [1] or None
Out[15]: True

1 in []
Out[17]: False

Below one returns None
1 in [] or None
**Returns None **
```

Why the below returns exception but for above None is returned

```
1 in None  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-71e8d29ac0d2>", line 1, in <module>
    1 in None
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: It returns `None`, and IPython simply does not display it

Comment: Then why this one doesn't return False  1 in None or []

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477850/python-and-or-operators-return-value) page.

Comment: How do you differentiate between None and Blank list ?

Comment: In case of 1 in None 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-71e8d29ac0d2>", line 1, in <module>
    1 in None
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Because None is not an iterable, you need an iterable in the right side of the **in** operator, that's the reason you get that error TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.The empty list is an iterable.

Comment: @vaultah why down vote for this ?

Comment: @HariomSingh what makes you think I downvoted this question? Anyway, hover over the downvote button to see the most common reasons.

Comment: @vaultah thanks ..:) since your comment was first .new to stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(following some edits, here are some notes hopefully will help out with workaround / explanation)

## Note 1 - how to turn a None into a False with not not

Use the `not` operator to turn a `None` into a boolean `True`. Likewise, use `not not` to turn that `None` into a boolean `False`.

```
In [4]: a = 1 in [] or None

In [5]: print(a)
None

In [6]: print(not a)
True

In [7]: print(not not a)
False
```

## Note 2 - how to turn a None into a False with bool()

As per a comment below (by @tobias_k), we can actually turn a `None` straight into a `False` with the shorter code:

```
In [8]: print(bool(None))
False
```

## Note 3 - in operator only works on iterable data type

The `in` operator only works on data structure that is an `iterable`. We can check if a data structure is an iterable with the `hasattr()` function.

For example, a `list`, `tuple`, and `range` are all iterables:

```
In [31]: hasattr([], '__iter__')
Out[31]: True

In [32]: hasattr((), '__iter__')
Out[32]: True

In [33]: hasattr(range(0), '__iter__')
Out[33]: True
```

Since these are iterables, the `in` operator works (i.e. doesn't throw an error):

```
In [34]: 1 in []
Out[34]: False

In [35]: 1 in ()
Out[35]: False

In [36]: 1 in range(0)
Out[36]: False
```

Data types such as `None`, `int`, `bool` are not iterables:

```
In [40]: hasattr(None, '__iter__')
Out[40]: False

In [41]: hasattr(1, '__iter__')
Out[41]: False

In [42]: hasattr(True, '__iter__')
Out[42]: False

In [43]: hasattr(False, '__iter__')
Out[43]: False
```

The `in` operator would therefore throw an error against these non iterable types. e.g.

```
In [44]: 1 in None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-71e8d29ac0d2> in <module>()
----> 1 1 in None

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

In [45]: 1 in 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-36200f7947c7> in <module>()
----> 1 1 in 1

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

In [47]: 1 in False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-0ba098e6e3c7> in <module>()
----> 1 1 in False

TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

In [48]: 1 in True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-5e7fb522bdca> in <module>()
----> 1 1 in True

TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

## Note 4 - Understanding "or" operator

See how the followings are evalulated:

- `1 in [] or None` -> `(1 in []) or None` -> `False or None` -> (short circuit to return the non-false) `None`
- `1 in [1, 2, 3] or None` -> `(1 in [1, 2, 3]) or None` -> `True or None` -> (short circuit to return the non-false) `True`
- `1 in None or []` -> `(error!!!) or []` -> (short circuit to throw the) `error!!!`
- `1 in None or [1, 2, 3]` -> `(error!!!) or [1, 2, 3]` -> (short circuit to throw the) `error!!!`

Note that `1 in None` always return an error. As explained in Note 3 previously, `in` operator only works on `iterable`, and `None` is not an iterable. Hence the error. (print out the above tests with `print()` to visualise it)

For the two erroneous cases you might want to consider adding some brackets to strengthen up the logic (as I've just read in @tobias_k 's answer). e.g.

- change `1 in None or []` to `1 in (None or [])` - this will evaluate to `1 in []` (bypassing the `None`) and should now return `False` (as expected)
- change `1 in None or [1, 2, 3]` to `1 in (None or [1, 2, 3])` - this will evaluate to `1 in [1, 2, 3]` (again, bypassing the `None`) and  should now return `True` (as expected)

Comment: This is something what I wanted to understand ...difference between None and False ..somewhat got it

Comment: @HariomSingh so turns out the error in your case is that the `in` only works against an iterable. i.e. `1 in []` would work (an empty `list` is still an iterable. This will rightfully return `False`, but a legitimate test!). Whereas `1 in None` would not work (because `None` is not an iterable. It will throw out an error.). I've edited my answer to add more info :)

Comment: @Atlas7 Thanks friend for explaining in detail

Comment: @HariomSingh more than welcome. I've just added Note 4 in the answer for completeness - regarding the "or" operator. Hopefully this will shed more intuition!

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at each of those in turn:

```
1 in None or []    -> (1 in None) or [] -> (Error)
1 in (None or [])  -> 1 in []           -> False
1 in (None or [1]) -> 1 in [1]          -> True
1 in [1] or None   -> True or None      -> True
1 in []                                 -> False
1 in [] or None    -> False or None     -> None (not printed)
```

There are a few key points to understand that:

- evaluation order is from left to right
- `x in y` has precedence over `y or z`
- `x or y` is evaluated as `x if x else y`
- a `None` result is *never printed* in the interactive shell

Comment: 1 in None  (is a exception)  but  1 in [] or None is None ?

Comment: @HariomSingh Yes. `1 in [] or None` evaluates as `(1 in []) or None` -> `False or None` -> `False if False or None` -> `None`

Answer (score 1):

Print the result to see it:

```
>>> print(1 in [] or None)
None
```

- None is not an iterable, you need an iterable in the right side of the **in** operator, that's the reason you get that error

  > TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

  The empty list **is** an iterable. An iterable is an object capable of returning its members one at a time.
- False is not preferred over None, nor None over False. This happens because that's how or operator works.

  ```
   >>> False or 5
   5
  ```

so

```
    >>> print(False or None)
    None
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it

Answer (score 0):

Your code evaluates from left to right. So `1 in []` is False. So between `False` and `None` you get `None`.

```
>>> False or None
>>> False or False
False
>>> None or False
False
```

Maybe a little more clearly. This is how it evaluates it.

1 in [] or None

Step 1: Evaluate 1 in [] So we have `False`

Step 2: Compare `False` and `None`. Since the first element is False we just get the second value.

Comment: Where is this behavior document  or priority is set between False and None

Comment: I edited it to try to be a little more clear. Since it evaluates from left to right if the first element is False, then it takes the second element.

Comment: *"None is "stronger" than False, so it wins."* How do you measure the strength of objects?