# Force Python to return 0 when returning 0 or None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a section in my code at the end of a recursive call that is as follows:

```
if (condition):
    # Some code here
else:
    return function_call(some_parameters) or function_call(some_parameters)
```

and it may evaluate to

```
return None or 0
```

where it will return 0 (an integer, as expected) 
or

```
return 0 or None
```

where it will return None (expected 0)

My question is, is it possible to have Python to return 0 (as an INTEGER) in the case immediately above?

Here is some code representing the scenario

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
def test_return():
    return 0 or None
def test_return2():
    return None or 0
def test_return3():
    return '0' or None #Equivalent of `return str(0) or None`

print( test_return() )
print( test_return2() )
print( test_return3() )

$ ./test.py
None
0
0
```

Note: 0 should be returned as an integer.

Comment: Why do you do that? Just type only 0, then it will return always 0.

Comment: What are the other possible return results?

Comment: ... `x = fun(); y = f();` then `return x if x is not None else y` ?

Comment: Check this question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477850/python-and-or-operators-return-value

Comment: Similar one in https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-or-operator-mean-in-Pythons-return-statement

Answer (score 3):

The Python behaves None, 0, {}, [], '' as Falsy. Other values will be considered as Truthy
So the following are normal behavior

```
def test_return():
    return 0 or None   # 0 is Falsy so None will be returned
def test_return2():
    return None or 0   # None is Falsy so 0 will be returned
def test_return3():
    return '0' or None # '0' is Truthy so will return '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorators, if its a specific case. Example below:

```
def test_return(f):
    def wrapper():
        result = f()
        if result == None or result == '0':
            return 0
        else:
            return result
    return wrapper

@test_return
def f1():
    return 0 or None

@test_return
def f2():
    return None or 0

@test_return
def f3():
    return '0' or None
```

Output:

```
print(f1())
print(f2())
print(f3())

0
0
0
```

Click here for [further read on decorators.](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Answer (score 0):

inline if else:

```
return 0 if (a == 0) + (b == 0) else None
```

by using the `+` arithmetic operator both `a` and `b` are evaluated, no 'shortcircuit' as with `or`

where `a`, `b` stand in for your function calls

```
tst = ((0, 0), (0, None), (None, 0), (None, None))


[0 if (a == 0) + (b == 0) else None for a, b in tst]
Out[112]: [0, 0, 0, None]
```